# How do I loop over a hash of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have this hash:

```
 h
 => {"67676.mpa"=>{:link=>"pool/sdafdsaff", :size=>4556}} 

>  h.each do |key, value|
>     puts key
>   puts value
>   end
67676.mpa
linkpool/sdafdsaffsize4556
```

How do I access the separate values in the value hash on the loop?

Comment: What would you like to see as output?

Comment: the appcoach shingara used worked out great....i must of drawn a blank...the answer was right in front of me...i had to do an inner loop

Comment: it's well known the output of puts on a hash is pretty useless, did you try "puts hash.inspect"?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Value is a Hash to so you need iterate on it or you can get only values:-

```
h.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  value.each do |k,v|
    puts k
    puts v
  end
end
```

or

```
h.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  value.values.each do |v|
    puts v
  end
end
```

Comment: here what if key isn't used anywhere ? . do we need to put a `?` in place of key ? ex : `|?, array|` is this valid syntax for `Ruby` ?

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala if the key isn't used in the iteration you should prefix it with an underscore like so `|_key, value|`

Answer (score 18):

You'll want to recurse through the hash, here's a recursive method:

```
def ihash(h)
  h.each_pair do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      puts "key: #{k} recursing..."
      ihash(v)
    else
      # MODIFY HERE! Look for what you want to find in the hash here
      puts "key: #{k} value: #{v}"
    end
  end
end
```

You can Then take any hash and pass it in:

```
h = {
    "x" => "a",
    "y" => {
        "y1" => {
            "y2" => "final"
        },
        "yy1" => "hello"
    }
}
ihash(h)
```

Comment: here what if key isn't used anywhere ? . do we need to put a `?` in place of key ? ex : `|?, array|` is this valid syntax ?

Comment: Keep it, just don't use it. question mark is not valid.

Answer (score 9):

I little improved Travis's answer, how about this gist:

https://gist.github.com/kjakub/be17d9439359d14e6f86

```
class Hash

  def nested_each_pair
    self.each_pair do |k,v|
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        v.nested_each_pair {|k,v| yield k,v}
      else
        yield(k,v)
      end
    end
  end

end

{"root"=>{:a=>"tom", :b=>{:c => 1, :x => 2}}}.nested_each_pair{|k,v|
  puts k
  puts v
}
```

Comment: @Travis R improved answer

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to separate out all three values in this case would be as follows:

```
h.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  puts value[:link]
  puts value[:size]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the values of a hash directly by calling `hash.values`. In this case you could do something like

```
> h = {"67676.mpa"=>{:link=>"pool/sdafdsaff", :size=>4556}}
> h.values.each do |key, value|
>   puts "#{key} #{value}"
> end

link pool/sdafsaff
size 4556
```