# Ruby - How to iterate over hash of hashes with array & non-array values

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following hash:

```
{
  "subtype"=>"example subtype",
  "contributors"=> {
    "Concept"=>["Example Contributor", "Example Contributor"],
    "Editor"=>["Example Contributor", "Example Contributor"],
    "Photographer"=>["Example"]
   },
   "publisher"=>"Example Publisher",
   "language"=>"Example Language",
   "dimensions"=>"Example Dimensions"
}
```

Where one can see that it is a hash of hashes, and some have string values and some have array values. I was wondering how I can iterate through this array so that I could have the following output, for example html:

```
<h3>example subtype</h3>

<h3>Concept</h3>
<p>Example Contributor, Example Contributor</p>

<h3>Editor</h3>
<p>Example Contributor, Example Contributor</p>

<h3>Photographer</h3>
<p>Example</p>

<h3>Publisher</h3>
<p>Example Publisher</p>

<h3>Language</h3>
<p>Example Language</p>

<h3>Dimensions</h3>
<p>Example Dimensions</p>
```

So far, I am trying to iterate through the array so following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9279884/436014) (haml):

```
- object_details.each do |key, value|
  %h3= key
  - value.each do |v|
    %p= v
```

Which of course fails immediately as the first item, `subtype` has no method `each` as it is not an array.

**I would take each value manually, but the hash may change if values are present or absent (for example, publisher or language may not always be present in the hash)**

Is there a smart way to iterate through this hash other than checking for the presence of each hash manually?

Comment: You could check the type of `value`, only iterate if it's a Hash/Array. Else just display the string. That would be sufficient enough.

Comment: @matov ah - should I use `.class`? I'll give it a go

Comment: you can use `value.kind_of?(Array)` as well, or just `.class`

Answer (score 2):

As @dax mention, and maybe cleaner like:

```
- object_details.each do |key, value|
  %h3= key
  %p= Array(value).join(', ')
```

I hope that helps

**Correction!** I didn't see the nested Hash. You can do something like this(in a helper)

```
   def headers_and_paragraphs(hash)
     hash.each do |k, v|
       if v.kind_of?(Hash)
         headers_and_paragraphs(v)
       else
         puts "h3: #{k}" # Replace that with content_tag or something similar
         puts "p: #{Array(v).join(', ')}" # Replace that with content_tag or something similar
       end
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

you're close.  try this:

```
- object_details.each do |key, value|
  %h3= key
  - if value.kind_of?(Array)
    -value.each do |v|
      %p= v
  - else
    %p= v
```

Comment: Also need to check for value.kind_of?(Hash)

Comment: @SomeGuy Having just the data from the question the test for Array would be enough in this case. (Note that OP wants only iterate over the `contributors` sub-hash) However, thanks for your comment below my - deleted - answer.. It makes not much sense anymore here since this one will already do it.. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$modifiedContent = []
def convert(hash)
   hash.each do |key, value|
      unless (value.kind_of?(Hash))
         unless (value.is_a? String and hash.first.first.eql? key and hash.first.last.eql? value)
            $modifiedContent << "<h3>#{key}</h3>"
            $modifiedContent << "<p>#{Array(value).join(', ')}</p>"
         else
            $modifiedContent << "<p>#{value}</p>"
         end
      else
         convert(value)
      end
      $modifiedContent << ""
   end
end

myHash = {
  "subtype"=>"example subtype",
  "contributors"=> {
    "Concept"=>["Example Contributor", "Example Contributor"],
    "Editor"=>["Example Contributor", "Example Contributor"],
    "Photographer"=>["Example"]
   },
   "publisher"=>"Example Publisher",
   "language"=>"Example Language",
   "dimensions"=>"Example Dimensions"
}

convert(myHash)
puts $modifiedContent
```